# Algorithm Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

You are given an array consist of numbers (size of array 10^5) and you need to divide the array into K partition (k<=500) such that sum of the minimum element of each partition is maximum

say array contains a1,a2,a3....... an
now f(x) =  min(a1,a2..ax) + min(a(x+1),a(x+2)... ay) +..........a(z+1)....a(n)

now f(x) should be maximum

where partition must be contiguous . 
 
Required Complexity . (n*k)

I simply fixed the maximum element one by one and tried to see, if it can be divided into K partition or not , if yes,I calculated the f(x)

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: I did in programming contest , but got wrong answer https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/9585930/

Comment: What is your exact issue here? Please mention some code or the use cases.

Comment: @SubhamGupta please post your attempt here

Comment: Also provide an example. Just want to confirm a few things

Comment: I simply took the maximum element and put in a single partition say n = 5, k = 4 and elements are 1 3 5 2 4  , so initially i fixed 5 as one partition and so we have 3 partition (1,3) 5 (2,4) which is not equal to k , so i discarded it ,and i put 4 in a single partition , then we have (1,3) 5 ,2,4 so answer will be . 1+5+2+4 . I know its wrong . can you suggest a good dp solution in (n*k) where k <=500

Answer (score 0):

Let `dp[i] = f(x)` when number of partitions is `i`
where f(x) is as defined by OP
Lets start solving it now -
Base case-

```
dp[n]=sum(array elements);
//ie when number of partitions is n we return sum of elements as each element is in different partition
```

Now,

```
dp[i-1] = dp[i] - min of partition collapsed in this step
```

So, now we simply have to find the partition that needs to be collapsed at each step. This can be done by brute force by taking two adjacent partitions at a time  and keeping tab of which partition's collapse is least favorable(can be done in O(n)).

So, overall time complexity is O(n*n-k) ans space complexity is O(n). Well this is limit to skills anyone who can help improve is welcome.